# How can I get node restrictions applied in an agent type's interface to take effect in the main agent when I run the model?

Tags: anylogic

In my pedestrian model, I have two ped types: RegPed (regular pedestrian) and SpePed (special pedestrian). In the RegPed interface, I have attached a polygonal node to represent 'field of vision' as shown:

[image]

Within my model, the RegPeds (green) are walking towards a target line using a PedGoTo block. On the way there, they may 'see' a SpePed (red) inside their field of vision as shown:

[image]

When this happens, I want the RegPed to abandon its initial PedGoTo command (named goToExit) and instead adopt a different command via the exit port. I have put the following in the field of vision node's interface to cancel goToExit when the node closes after a SpePed enters it:

[image]

However, the following problems arise when I try to run the model:

[image]

Is this happening because the field of vision node is within the RegPed interface and not the main agent interface? Are there any solutions which result in the same desired functionality?

Here is my model hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: You need to understand (and share) your model hierarchy, see https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Comment: I have now shared the model hierarchy. I also read the help page and tried main.goToExit.cancel(RegPed) to try and pull the function goToExit from the main agent however there are still issues. Could you explain what is required please.

Comment: no time. What issue remains? `main.goToExit.cancel(RegPed)` sounds like a good start. Feel free to open a new issue (SOF does not work like a forum, see some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow )

Comment: Two issues: 'RegPed cannot be resolved to a variable' and 'main cannot be resolved'. Unsure why this is happening?

Comment: Its your model hierarchy. Your screenshots do not show the actual hierarchy, it depends on how you embed agents, if at all.

Comment: Sorry, where should I go to show the actual hierarchy?

Comment: No place, it is extremely flexible and depends on how you setup the model... Hence my link above :)

Comment: Ok I see, I have managed to fix the 'main cannot be resolved' issue with: ((Main)getOwner()).goToExit.cancel(RegPed) however the issue of 'RegPed cannot be resolved to a variable' still remains. I am really struggling to figure out why RegPed is not recognised (as mentioned in my post, the node in which this code is being implemented is within the RegPed interface itself so I don't understand how embedment is the issue).

Comment: there is no element called `RegPed` in the agent type you call this code. Pls open a new issue with the relevant details on this specific problem if you still struggle. SOF does not work like a back-and-forth forum, its a Q&A place :)

Comment: oh, and start using code-complete as it shows you what you can write and what is not possible: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/using-intelli-sense.html